# How can I wait Until a Form Handle Has Been Created Before Using Its' Components?

Tags: c#, winforms, synchronization, handle

I am dynamically instantiating a Form. I cannot interact with the components (such as a TextBox) on the Form until the handle has been created (else, an exception will be thrown).

Currently I block the thread using a while loop:

```
public void OutputDesktopFrame(MessagingService service, DesktopFrame desktopFrame)
{
    IRemoteDesktopView view = GetView(service);
    view.UpdateFrame(desktopFrame);
}

private IRemoteDesktopView GetView(MessagingService service)
{
    T view;
    bool viewExists = _views.TryGetValue(service, out view);

    if (viewExists == false)
    {
        view = CreateAndShowView(service);
    }

    return view;
}

private T CreateAndShowView(MessagingService service)
{
    T remoteDesktopView = new T();

    _views.Add(service, remoteDesktopView);

    Thread pumpThread = new Thread(() => remoteDesktopView.ShowDialog());
    pumpThread.Start();


    while (remoteDesktopView.IsHandleCreated == false)
    {
        //Do not return until the handle has been created!
    }

    return remoteDesktopView;
}
```

I do not like this mechanism. I am looking for an *elegant* solution.

Please take into account that I am coding against an interface. I thought about using a ManualResetEvent or something of the like but having to implement and handle the ManualResetEvent within each Form that implements the interface doesn't sound appealing to me. If you don't agree with me. that's just fine. I merely suspect my current solutions are not the most elegant.

Comment: The snippet is pretty useless, the Handle property will always have a valid value after the Show() method returns.  By far the simplest and cleanest way to deal with a thread trying to whack a form is to not start the thread until the form's Load event fires.

Comment: @HansPassant You make a good point. I have updated my question with a more complete code sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add code to a `HandleCreated` event handler like this:

```
private void Form1_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //your code
}
```

The event is not listed in Properties window, you have to register the event handler using code:

```
HandleCreated += Form1_HandleCreated;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with more context. I don't think this event is suitable given the updated question.

Comment: @Alex I guess the exception was thrown at `view.UpdateFrame(desktopFrame);`? If not, could you highlight or point out the line at which the exception was thrown?

Comment: @Alex but you said this `...(else, an exception will be thrown)...`, if so I don't figure out what your problem is. (although the question title seems to be very meaningful).

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for the handle to be created somehow. 
So you will end up with something like `while (form.IsHandleCreated == false) { ... }` somewhere in your code. 
The only question is where to put it.

If you do it like in your example above, you need to code the `while` loop every time you create a form  If you choose the alternative you mentioned, using an event raised by the form, you need to implement it in each form (and create an event handler and hook it up).

I don't know if `CreateAndShowForm()` is a framework method, or something you can change yourself. If you can change it, that's where I would put the waiting. That way you only need to code it once.

Another approach to avoid the code duplication would be handling it in the form, implementing it in your own abstract form base class, and deriving you actual forms from that class. In my opinion, that is complete overkill for this issue - way too  much work for very little gain.

If you can't change `CreateAndShowForm()`, I recommend going with the example above - yes, it definitely isn't elegant, but it gets the work done, the source code is easy to understand, and it doesn't require the additional work of event handling.

Comment: This is a good answer and I thank you. But it does not answer my question. It's my fault for not being clear enough. I have updated my question.